# GoogleTagManager firebase can't get data from ios

Tags: google-tag-manager

I used Google Tag Manager (just call it GTM) in our iOS app for analysis.
GTM has 2 ways to integrate - Firebase or legacy. 
I chose the recommended one - Firebase - and configured a new container for GA.

I can see the log when app is running but no data in GA.
The only connection between GA and GTM is a trackID that is written in the container file in JSON format.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i met the same problem before, 
i didn't know why , but after giving every value a default value, i can get data in GA. 
maybe help.